# EntityManager.persist() doesn't save to database

Tags: java, ejb, entitymanager, persist

`EntityManager.persist()` doesn't save to database with a new entity bean I added to my project. Previously similarly added beans saves to the database.

I have tried adding `EntityManager.getTransaction().commit()`, which results in an error and `EntityManager.flush()`, but that results in `TransactionRequiredException`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There may be different reasons for that. First of all, check your persistence.xml. Do you have either the entity listed or the line "<exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>" ?

Answer (score 0):

Add `EntityManager.getTransaction().begin()` before `persist()` and then `commit()` afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

All the transactional operation should be kept between begin and commit.

```
EntityManager.getTransaction().begin()
  .
  .  
  EntityManager.persist();
  EntityManager.flush()
  .
  .
 EntityManager.getTransaction().commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! The begin call was the thing missing here and also I'm using JTA, which means I have to manage it like this:

```
UserTransaction transaction = (UserTransaction)new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/UserTransaction");
transaction.begin();
EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
em.persist(YourBean);
transaction.commit();
```